# managing marshmallow synchronisation

Tags: settings, sync, motorola

My wife and I bought some Android phones at about the same time. She bought a Motorola Moto G2, I bought a Moto E2. They run Android 6 (Marshmallow), System versions 24.41.34 and 24.51.39 respectively

If we go to apps, settings, accounts, Google we see different screens

[image]
[image]

My E2 has toggle switches that allow me to choose what data gets automatically synchronised from my phone to my online google account. Her G2 doesn't.

How can she turn off all the synchronisation for data she wants only on the phone and not online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that on the previous screen, where it lists accounts, on the menu at top right (three vertical dots) you can turn auto-sync on or off globally. This affects whether the screens shown above have individual on/off switches or not.

Comment: My wife found the answer a few minutes after I had gone to all the trouble of writing this question. Typical! ☺